# Srednicki QFT ch34: invariants of the Lorentz group

Tags: group-theory, tensor-calculus, group-representations, lorentz-symmetry, invariants

In chapter 34 of his [Quantum Field theory handbook](http://web.physics.ucsb.edu/~mark/qft.html), Srednicki discusses invariants of the Lorentz group and how they appear in the decomposition in irreducible representations of Lorentz tensors.  As one example [Eq. 34.32], the fully antisymmetric Levi-Civita tensor $\epsilon^{\mu\nu\rho\sigma}$ appears in the direct product of

$$(2,2) \otimes (2,2) \otimes (2,2)\otimes (2,2)~=~(1,1)_A \oplus \ldots \tag{34.32} $$

Here, $(2,2)$ denotes the irreducible representation corresponding to the fourvector (or equivalently a tensor with one left-handed and one right-handed spinor index) and $(1,1)$ is the singlet.
Is there a straightforward way to see why there can be a singlet there that is antisymmetric?  The singlet I can understand of course from the direct product rules of the $SU(2)$ group representations, but not the antisymmetric nature.

Am familiar with all the basics of Lie groups, $SU(N)$, Young tableaux and such, but fail to see how it translates to the case of the Lorentz group here.  I guess my more general question would be how can one determine the (anti)symmetric nature of the irreducible representations in the decomposition of a general Lorentz group tensor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I) Here is one derivation. Let us first consider the undotted 2-component left Weyl spinor. The decomposition of the 4th tensor power in terms of irreducible representations/[Young diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Young_tableau) reads:
$$\begin{array}{rcccccc} 
\underline{\large\bf 2}^{\otimes 4} &\cong&
2~\underline{\large\bf 1}&\oplus&
3~\underline{\large\bf 3}&\oplus&
\underline{\large\bf 5}\cr\cr
[~~]^{\otimes 4} &\cong&
2~\begin{array}{rl} [~~]&[~~]\cr [~~] &[~~]\end{array}&\oplus&
3~\begin{array}{rcl} [~~]&[~~]&[~~]\cr [~~] \end{array}&\oplus&
\begin{array}{rccl} [~~]& [~~] & [~~] & [~~] \end{array}
\end{array}$$
Interestingly, there are 2 singlets! If we define the shorthand notation
$$I~:=~\epsilon^{\alpha\beta}\epsilon^{\gamma\delta}, \qquad II~:=~\epsilon^{\alpha\gamma}\epsilon^{\beta\delta}, \qquad III~:=~\epsilon^{\alpha\delta}\epsilon^{\beta\gamma}, $$
there is a [Schouten identity](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=schouten+identity)
$$I-II+III~=~0.$$
Two independent tensors that each correspond to the singlet Young diagram
$$\begin{array}{rl} [~~]&[~~]\cr [~~] &[~~]\end{array}$$
are
$$ A~:=~~\epsilon^{\alpha\gamma}\epsilon^{\beta\delta}+\epsilon^{\alpha\delta}\epsilon^{\beta\gamma}~=~II+III,$$
and
$$ B~:=~\epsilon^{\alpha\beta}\epsilon^{\gamma\delta}-\epsilon^{\alpha\delta}\epsilon^{\beta\gamma}
~=~I-III~=~II-2III.$$
The tensor $A$ is manifestly symmetric under $\alpha\leftrightarrow \beta$ and $\gamma\leftrightarrow \delta$. The tensor $B$ is manifestly symmetric under $\alpha\leftrightarrow \gamma$ and $\beta\leftrightarrow \delta$.

II) There is a similar story for the dotted 2-component right Weyl spinor.
So there are altogether $2\times 2= 4$ singlets on the rhs. of Srednicki's eq. (34.32)! It turns out that the antisymmetric singlet $$(\underline{\large\bf 1},\underline{\large\bf 1})_A,$$ which is totally antisymmetric under permutation of spinor indices pairs
$$  (\alpha,\dot{\alpha})\quad\leftrightarrow \quad (\beta,\dot{\beta})\quad\leftrightarrow \quad (\gamma,\dot{\gamma})\quad\leftrightarrow \quad (\delta,\dot{\delta}), $$
corresponds (up to an overall normalization) to the following linear combination of tensors
$$ A\dot{B}-B\dot{A}, $$
in a hopefully obvious notation.